# How to alternate between two infinite loops?

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, infinite-loop

I want to alternate between two infinite loops; how can I achieve this. My code is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Master loop
    while (1)

    // loop # 1
    while (1) {
        printf("I am in loop #1");
    }

    // loop # 2
    while (1) {
        printf("I am in loop #2");
    }
} // end of master loop
```

What can I do to alternate between loop #1 and loop #2 ? I am just testing an idea to check / compare some results between two loop in time (temporally) so as to find some deviations/fault in time line.

Comment: Ummmm....first of all, you don't make the inner loops infinite. Either that, or `break` out of the first inner loop.

Comment: *Not* what you're doing now? By definition an infinite loop is... infinite. you don' break it. How about an if-then-else in *one* loop (assuming your *real* loops are significantly more in-depth than these)? is this for some state-machine or some-such?

Comment: If I were to answer this question as it is and not tell you to do something else, I'd be forced to suggest `goto`.

Comment: It may be better to explain what you are trying to accomplish, IE why the need for the two loops, and then we can provide you with some answers or alternative solutions.

Comment: Seriously `Shan`. You are creating C++ inception!

Comment: Do it the same way you would enumerate all pairs of non-negative integers.

Comment: @KerrekSB, You mean like this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function

Comment: The question does not contain C++ code. It is illegal in C++ to not declare the return type of a function. Though I believe that code would be legal in some version of C.

Comment: Common guys. This is our opportunity to educate OP on threads. Anyone?

Comment: @JohanLundberg Thanks. You got my actual intent. I asked earlier a similar question, but it was beaten to evaporation :)

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes, my real loops have lot more to do  and its kind of some state machine.

Comment: @Shan I see. Then Seth's answer and Johans link within it will likely get you kick started in the proper direction. But consider this: If the code in two different threads is designed to execute with exclusive synchronous alternate action (toggle back and forth with no *real* code in *both* executing simultaneously) chances are threads are overkill. *Concurrent* execution is ideally the point of multi-threaded design. Embrace that; don't fight against it.

Answer (score 6):

Threads:

```
std::thread t1([]() { while(true) printf("I am in loop #1"); }),
            t2([]() { while(true) printf("I am in loop #2"); });

t1.join();
t2.join(); // only necessary if t1 is not really an infinite loop
```

You can modify that code to make each thread only execute when some condition is true, for example.

Comment: For a more complete example, including simple communication between the two threads, and the possoibility to stop. Look at the example found here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
while (1) {
    printf("I am in loop #1");
    printf("I am in loop #2"); // Not really but let's pretend we are
}
```

If you seriously want two loops:

```
while (1) {
myfirstloop:
    printf("I am in loop #1");

    goto mysecondloop;
}

while (1) {
mysecondloop:
    printf("I am in loop #2");

    goto myfirstloop;
}
```

Of course, the second code doesn't make sense. But hey, it's two loops!

Answer (score 2):

```
bool move = true;
while (true) {
    while (found) {
       // do work
       if (condition) { found = false; }
    }
    while (!found) {
       // do work
       if (condition) { found = true; }
    }
}
```

The provided answer can be applied to very complex cases -- as well as to the simple case you mention.

Answer (score 2):

Using a break statement in each inner loop will exit that loop and go to the next loop. Quite simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
// Master loop
 while (1) {

// loop # 1
  while (1) {
       printf("I am in loop #1");
       if(something)
           break;
  }

// loop # 2
  while (1) {
       printf("I am in loop #2");
       if(something)
           break;
  }
 }
} // end of master loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (1)
{
    while (1) {
        loop1:
        printf("I am in loop #1\n");
        goto loop2;
   }

   while (1) {
       loop2:
       printf("I am in loop #2\n");
       goto loop1;
   }
}
```

But i have to say that the best way to do it always using multiple threads

Answer (score -1):

You should have 2 threads and have some synchronization mechanism like semaphore etc if your 
intention of alternate is like a reader writer issue.

Comment: This answer does not add anything not already said